# "Image of the week" is causing mixed content error

Tags: support, status-completed, featured-photo

My browser is reporting mixed HTTPS and HTTP content on the main site because the "Image of the week" in the header is HTTP:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJKvB.jpg" alt="Random Flower in Lawn">
```

Given that the rest of the imgur user-provided images were [changed to HTTPS-only](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/), it is obviously an oversight that whatever form the moderators have to edit the image of the week allows non-HTTPS URLs.

I'm tagging this as [support](/questions/tagged/support) because the immediate problem is the image right now, and it will probably be a sufficient work-around for the mods to add the URL protocol to their mental checklist for updating the photo. Besides, since they know what the actual interface is, they're better placed than me to file a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I guess the issue is a lot of the photos submitted are a few years old, before they made the switch.  It's not a big deal for us to try to remember to make sure it's https

Comment: Interesting. Did the HTTPS-ification not include posts in meta?

Comment: Related (or dupe?): [“Parts of this page are insecure” warning from Firefox](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5450)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Parts of this page are insecure" warning from Firefox](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/parts-of-this-page-are-insecure-warning-from-firefox)

Comment: lol, it feels weird to VtC a meta page as dupe. It's just so rare... =)

Comment: @AndrewT This is not a dupe as it is a distinct occurrence.  Dupe rules for Meta are a bit different since it also serves as something of a ticketing platform.

Comment: @scottbb see above comment.

Comment: @AJHenderson sure, I should have remembered. Un-VtC'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed now.  Sorry.  I missed that the image link wasn't https.  The tool for setting that is literally just a block of HTML code that the mods are given access to directly modify and it gets injected.  It apparently doesn't have any automatic https change over applied.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but since it's HTML you could leave a comment to remind you (plural) in the future.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it shouldn't be hard for me to remember.  I just didn't realize they weren't automatically doing the conversion.  I've dealt with many broken lock icons in my day. :)  I'd rather not put a comment that has to be part of every page load.

Comment: If you're *that* worried about saving bytes, how about bare `//` URLs?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I like this plan!  I'll admit I honestly didn't know (or had forgotten about) that shortcut.